# why I am getting i at the end of char array?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    char code[n];
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(code, n);

    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

        if((code[i]>='A' && code[i]<='Z') || (code[i]>='a' && code[i]<='z')) {
            code[j] = code[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    code[j] = '\0';
    cout<<code;
    return 0;
}
```

input :

```
10
Ajith@#
```

Expected output :

```
Ajith
```

Acutal output I'm getting :

```
Ajithi
```

why I am getting i at end of array ?
I need to print only alphabets ignoring numbers and special symbols. please help me on this

Comment: [Variable-length arrays are not really part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), use `std::vector` instead. Or, in this case, `std::string`.

Comment: Also please learn about [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: And that `ignore` call might not be enough. What if the user presses a lot of other characters after the number, but before the `Enter` key?

Comment: `std::string code;...code.erase(std::remove_if(code.begin(), code.end(), [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalpha(c):}), code.end());`

Comment: `int n; ... char code[n];` You will never see arrays declared this way in any good C++ book.  Why?  Because this isn't valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

You tell the program that the input will be ten characters, including null-terminator.

Then you input only *seven* characters. With the null-terminator that leaves two uninitialized elements of the array, and those two elements will have *indeterminate* values.

Your loop still uses all ten characters, and using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

What is likely happening is that there's some data after the null-terminator that your program believes is characters.

The solution is `std::string` and only iterating over the actual length of the string, copying to another `std::string`.

Comment: Or, at least, paying attention to how many characters `getline()` actually reads into the `char[]`, which is reported by `cin.gcount()`.